# How to interpret AとB、Cが違う

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

> エアコンの中のコンピューターが、**部屋の壁の近くと窓の近くなど、温度が違う**場所を調べて、ちょうどいい温度にすることもできます。
>   The air conditioning's computer will check places where the temperature is different between near the walls and near the windows and can choose the perfect temperature.

I'm struggling with the part in bold. Does 部屋の壁の近くと窓の近くなど、温度が違う (on it's own) mean "the temperatures are different between the places near the walls and the places near the windows"? If so, I'm feeling a little uncomfortable about the lack of a と on the end of 窓の近くなど. Would it be okay to add one?

If I'm right, then I think the computer checks the places where there is a temperature difference between the walls and the windows, but that makes absolutely no logical sense. I'm very confused.

Comment: 「食材と食器など、用途の違うもの」「大型犬と小型犬などサイズの違う犬」「新幹線と在来線など幅の違う線路」「冷凍のご飯とスーパーで購入したおかずなど、温度の違う2品」... などと同じ形じゃないですかね・・

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have parsed the sentence a bit incorrectly. 温度が違う場所 is what the computer checks. 部屋の壁の近くと窓の近く as a whole is marked with など, and works as an example of 温度が違う場所.

> エアコンの中のコンピューターが、｛温度が違う場所｝を調べる。
>   The air conditioner's computer will check ((if there is) a pair of) places where the temperatures is different.
>
> エアコンの中のコンピューターが、**｛部屋の壁の近くと窓の近く｝など、**｛温度が違う場所｝を調べる。
>   The air conditioner's computer will check (a pair of) places where the temperature is different, **such as (a pair of) window-side and wall-side places in a room.**

Note that 場所 in this sentence actually refers to a pair of two places with different temperatures. That's why 壁の近く and 窓の近く are connected using と.

Comment: I gave that +1 just hoping it would be the 100k one! lol

Answer (score 4):

I think the computer can choose any 2 points where are different temperatures and tell the air conditioner to send warm or cool air to fix it for the perfect one. [壁の近くと窓の近く] is an example and can be any 2 places where the temperatures are different. I think you can not add "と”　but you can add similar one "の”.

And I remember your past question 学校が子どもの親などとトラブルになる.It is the similar thing.The answer you confirmed is "the school and parents" get in trouble with...
I understand the parents as a representation of all the parties which involved in. But there are other people might be involved in. Therefore I assume you might write "the school and parents and so on".

Answer (score 3):

> エアコンの中のコンピューターが、部屋の壁の近く**と**窓の近く**など**、温度が違う場所を調べて、ちょうどいい温度にすることもできます。

In my opinion, the sentence might be poorly written or make a small typo, which is the cause of your confusion. The more correct or easy-to-understand version would be:

> エアコンの中のコンピューターが、部屋の『壁の近く』**や**『窓の近く』**など**、温度が違う場所を調べて、ちょうどいい温度にすることもできます。

*The air conditioning's computer can even check the places where the temperature is **different (from the major places that have mean/ordinary temperature**), **such as** the near-the-wall place **and** the near-the-window place, and can choose the perfect temperature.*

I don't think, however, the original Japanese sentence is incorrect grammatically.

～や～など and ～と～など can be used equally in this context.

There is no "between" in the context.

部屋の壁の近くと窓の近く**の間**など= **between** near the walls and near the windows

edit) My interpretation seems not good than other interpretations.